# Execute a return statement in the rest of the code when used in a function

Tags: c#

I've used a method, which I want to stop executing the rest of the code when it's called.

The function is:

```
class Helper
{
    public static void MessageTextQues(string text, Action action)
    {
        MessageQues messageQues = new MessageQues();

        messageQues.lblText.Text = text;
        messageQues.ShowDialog();

        if (messageQues.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            action();
        }
        if (messageQues.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Call function is:

```
Helper.MessageTextQues(
                $@"This material '{dgMaterials.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value}' will delete. Do you want? ",
                () => material.MaterialDelete(Convert.ToInt32(dgMaterials.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value)));

            btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);  //This code I don't want to read when No is selected
```

Comment: Change `MessageTextQues()` to return `bool`, and make it return `true` when you want the caller to continue and `false` if not. Then just call it in an `if` and respond to the return value appropriately.

Comment: Alternatively, since you already pass an Action to the procedure, only to be executed on 'Yes', you  could also make a param array actions, and execute all actions on 'Yes' (or "add" the action of the button to the other action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe have `MessageTextQues` return a `bool`, so you can `return true;` (at the end) or `return false;` (when escaping early due to an invalid state), to indicate whether to proceed, and use:

```cs
if (Helper.MessageTextQues(...))
{
    btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code into the action you pass to your `MessageTextQues` method:

```
Helper.MessageTextQues(
                $@"This material '{dgMaterials.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value}' will delete. Do you want? ",
                () =>
                {
                    material.MaterialDelete(Convert.ToInt32(dgMaterials.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value));
                    btnRefresh_Click(sender, e);
                });
```